# selectize initial load of options but non persistent

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I am initially, via ajax, loading options into an already initialized selectize control.

```
// being called after an ajax requests
addOption: (items) => {
    let selectize = this.control_element[0].selectize;
    selectize.addOption(items);
    // not sure if needed
    selectize.refreshOptions();
}
```

I do want these initial items to be persistent, however I do want user created items to be persistent. So I have set persistent to `false` on the options.

How do I reconcile the two? Because if I remove the loaded values, they will not persist and will be removed. Is there a flag that I can use or call a method to regenerate the option list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you just have to use `selectize.registerOption(o)` (Note to self: Just have a peek at the source code beforehand!).